# Share one url but linkback to other in FB

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently working on Web app which allows to share on Facebook. 
My app contains a few questions and then generates a picture(depends from previous answers to my questions) and opens results page.

I want to share the content of result page and I'm using OG metatags to specify  what is shared on FB.

For example:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My app" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.myapp.com/step=share&shareid=hi43uib23ni" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.myapp.com/images/hi43uib23ni.jpg" />
```

I have also included FB APP id and some image sizing tags.

The problem is that when I share results on FB and than click on my POST, it brings me back to http://www.myapp.com/step=share&shareid=hi43uib23ni but what i need is http://www.myapp.com

The idea is that I share my results on FB and inform others about this app. And when they click on my post they actually have ability to do the test by themselves..not to see my results...Any suggestions on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect human visitors that arrive at the address `http://www.myapp.com/step=share&shareid=hi43uib23ni` either

- via JavaScript (which the FB scraper does not care about), `location.href="…"`, or
- server-side – in that case, you need to implement an exception for the FB scraper, so that it does not get redirected (because then it would read the OG meta data from `http://www.myapp.com/`, and that’s not what you want.)
  The scraper can be recognized by the User-Agent header it sends – see Like button social plugin FAQ, I think the exact value the scraper sends is mentioned in there.